# slide animation effect in angular is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I am new to web development Trying to create a sliding page in angular ng-view but its not working as expected when the page two is entering its displaying below the page one till page one is available.please see the code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jhg98DPICDgX1ltFDKVB?p=preview).

```
.slide.ng-enter{
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
.slide.ng-enter-active{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.slide.ng-leave{
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.slide.ng-leave-active{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

I also need to make the page one slide from left to right.Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added position: absolute to .slide. If that is acceptable in the project you are working then the below solution works fine. Please check the updated plunker.

```
.slide {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/qC0YS2Gj3ddiNvuhjKzV?p=preview

Comment: thank you so much,do you have any idea how to make slide from left to right when page 2 is clicked

Comment: Updated plunker below that slides from left to right..
https://plnkr.co/edit/qC0YS2Gj3ddiNvuhjKzV?p=preview